# Plotting two figures in one graph (Python)

Tags: python, plotly, metatrader5

I want to display two figures in one graph, so that they overlapping each other...

here is my code:

```
ohlc_data = pd.DataFrame(mt.copy_rates_range('EURUSD',
                                        mt.TIMEFRAME_D1,
                                        datetime(2021, 1, 1), 
                                        datetime.now()))

ohlc_data2 = pd.DataFrame(mt.copy_rates_range('EURUSD',
                                        mt.TIMEFRAME_H4,
                                        datetime(2021, 1, 1), 
                                        datetime.now()))

fig = px.line(ohlc_data, x=ohlc_data['time'], y=ohlc_data['close'])
fig2 = px.line(ohlc_data2, x=ohlc_data2['time'], y=ohlc_data2['close'])
```

how can I plot fig & fig2 in one graph instead of seperate ones?

and here the imports:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: what is `px` and what is `mt`? are you using matplotlib or another library?

Comment: i imported plotly.express as "px" and MetaTrader5 as "mt"

Comment: @zookeeper85,  please add **all** of the `imports` at the top otherwise users trying to help you have to guess those.  Sometimes it is obvious other times not.  Here is a guide:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse this example, if two plots share the same x-axis:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig1 = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
fig1.update_traces(line_color='red')

df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Australia'")
fig2 = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Australia')
fig1.update_traces(line_color='black')

fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data)
fig3.update_xaxes(title_text="Yea")
fig3.update_yaxes(title_text="Life Expenses")

fig3.show()
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for ! thank you! :)